# convert django datetime format to template type formatting

Tags: django, django-views

How can i convert django datetime field to the format that shows in the template.
Date time field in database is '2015-05-1 00:01:00', i want to show it in 'May 1, 2015, 12:01 a.m.' format in the view functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import datetime

template_type_value = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M').strftime('%b %d, %Y, %I:%M %p')
```

Comment: Check this [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) for further clarification on python date time formatting.

Answer (score 2):

That's not the django way, you should use django template formatters, this is how it works:
`{{ value|date:"N j, o,"  }} {{ value|time:"P"}}`
`April 22, 2015, 11:53 a.m.`

Where value is the datetime value you retrieve from the database with DateTimeField

You should make the changes in your templates because they are the one responsible for the display, your views shouldn't be bloated with something like the accepted answer
Edit: unless you are doing ajax lol

the docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date

Comment: previous answer was right.I have a ajax request to the server for editing content that displayed on the page.On the page it shows the template type formatting.So i need to convert the json response to the template like formatting.

Comment: oh ok then, you just need to specify that.